# Unable to open google map

Tags: flex4

I have created a Google Map application in Flex and deployed on apache-tomcat-7.0.5. It is opening perfectly on local machine but when I am trying to opening on other machine in Network it showing "Initialization failed: please check the API key, swf location, version and network availability." instead of Google map. I am unable to determine what went wrong.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is normal. You must use get an API key : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/intro#API_Key

When accessing at appplication from localhost there is no API key required. But when you laod the application form an ip or a doamin you need a key.